# Git go back to head from particular SHA

Tags: git

I did a

```
git checkout <sha>
```

to take my local master branch to a particular sha, some time in the past

I now want to go back to the current, latest commit.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to checkout the branch you were previously working on:

```
git checkout master
```

Answer (score 4):

Given answers only work if you worked on `master` before doing your `git checkout <sha>` or if you could remember your last branch name.

However, if you don't remember which branch you worked on (the last week when you did the `git checkout`):

```
git checkout -
```

Will check out the last branch that was checked out.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean 'the current, latest commit on master` then

```
git checkout master
```

will work. Otherwise, substitute the branch name you want.